# TypeError xxx.subscribe is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am writing an application based on Angular 4 and Material 2. It works "live" but when I decided to write some unit tests I got into trouble.

It seems that I have a systematic error that results in the following error message:

> TypeError: this.serviceXXX.getAll(...).subscribe is not a function

This is my service code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class CompanyService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }


    getAll() {
        return this.http.get('/api/companies', this.jwt()).map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }


    private jwt() {
        // create authorization header with jwt token
        const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            const headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.token });
            return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        }
    }

}
```

My component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';
import {Company} from '../../../models/_models';
import {CompanyService} from '../../../services/_services'
import {Db} from './data-source'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import {CompanyDetailsComponent} from '../company-details/company-details.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-company',
  templateUrl: './company-listing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./company-listing.component.scss']
})
export class CompanyListingComponent implements OnInit {

  errorMessage: string;
  dataSource;
  displayedColumns: string[] = [   'name', 'btns' ];

  constructor(public service: CompanyService, public dialog: MdDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadAll();
  }

  onCreate() {
    this.showDetail(new Company('name'));
  }

  onEditUser(user: Company) {
  }

  onRemove(item: Company) {

  }

  loadAll() {
    this.service.getAll()
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                   this.dataSource =  new Db(data);
                },
                err => {
                    this.errorMessage = err;
                });
  }

  showDetail(item: Company) {
  this.dialog.open(CompanyDetailsComponent, {
         disableClose: true,
          data: {
          item: Company
        }
    }
    ).afterClosed().subscribe(
        result => {this.loadAll(); }
      )
  }


}
```

and my test class:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CompanyListingComponent } from './company-listing.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { MaterialModule, MdTableModule } from '@angular/material'
import { CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk';
import { CompanyService } from './../../../services/_services';
import {mock, } from 'ts-mockito';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

describe('CompanyComponent', () => {
  let component: CompanyListingComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CompanyListingComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    const companyServiceMock: CompanyService = mock(CompanyService)
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MaterialModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                MdTableModule,
                CdkTableModule],
      declarations: [ CompanyListingComponent ],
      providers: [ {provide: CompanyService, useValue: companyServiceMock} ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CompanyListingComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I have found and read a lot of questions with similar problems,, but no of the solutions works for me.

Can anyone see what I done wrong.

Comment: Only during testing its giving error or is it working fine when running normally ?

Comment: Im not familiar with the Mocking framework you are using, but dont you need to setup a stub for the getAll() method before you use the service mock ?

Comment: +1 to Dean: you're using a mock service, but you don't tell it what to return when its getAll() method is called. So it most probably returns null or undefined or an empty object.

Comment: yes, it needs to return an observable for there to be a subscribe method

Comment: @lg.lindstrom How did you fix it. Could you please provide some details.

Comment: Ok found it https://github.com/NagRock/ts-mockito/issues/35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation in [ts-mockito says](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mockito#stubbing-method-calls), try stubbing the getAll method in your test class:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  const companyServiceMock: CompanyService = mock(CompanyService);
  when(companyServiceMock.getAll()).thenReturn(Observable.of([]));
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [MaterialModule,
              RouterTestingModule,
              MdTableModule,
              CdkTableModule],
    declarations: [ CompanyListingComponent ],
    providers: [ {provide: CompanyService, useValue: companyServiceMock} ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));
```

I think the error occurs because your companyServiceMock doesn't have `getAll()` method defined using the stubbing.

Comment: I think you are correct. I've added this line : when(companyServiceMock.getAll).thenReturn( () => Observable.of([]) ) and now I have this error message:   Failed: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Comment: @lg.lindstrom where is this `add` property used? I can't seem to find it in your code

Comment: I have no idea where it is used,,,   maybe in ts-mockito,, but I can't find it there either ..

Comment: @lg.lindstrom In which line and files does this `Failed: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined` occurs?

Comment: MethodStubSetter.webpackJsonp.../../../../ts-mockito/lib/MethodStubSetter.js.MethodStubSetter.thenReturn (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:37519:51)

Comment: ok,, cant read property add problems was missing brackets. Corrected now. Back on my first error,,   TypeError: this.serviceXXX.getAll(...).subscribe is not a function